# Symfony does not remove Element from ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine, arraycollection

i want to remove an role from the roles-ArrayCollection in the User Entity.
User and Role have an M:N connection.

In my Controller:

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($userId);
  $user->removeRole($roleID);
  $em->flush();
```

If I execute the controller, there are no error messages.
But the Role is still assigned to the user.

User Entity

```
namespace Chris\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usermanagement_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Chris\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements  UserInterface,\Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->isActive = true;

    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    public function setRoles($roles){
        $this->roles[] = $roles;
    }

    public function removeRole($role){
            unset($this->roles->toArray()[$role]);

    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $vorname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $nachname;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $letzterLogin;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;



    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Role Entity

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: christianschade
 * Date: 02.02.15
 * Time: 19:29
 */

namespace Chris\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Role
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Chris\UserBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="usermanagement_roles")
 */

class Role implements RoleInterface {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    public function getRole() {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "User", inversedBy = "roles")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $users
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }


    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->role = $roles;

        // allows for chaining
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Chris\UserBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy = "groups")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $group
     */
    private $group;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $group
     */
    public function setGroup($group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use FOSUserbundle? https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/

Comment: Because I started developing without FOS. It would be much more effort to start new with FOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ArrayCollection::removeElement()` to remove the role.

```
public function removeRole($role)
{
    $this->roles->removeElement($role);
}
```

On a side note, I feel your `getRoles()` implementation is unorthodox as it would be recommended to return the ArrayCollection as is and call `toArray()` if you need to once you have retrieved it.

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i get:  `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Chris\UserBundle\Entity\User::removeRole() must be an instance of Chris\UserBundle\Entity\RoleInterface, instance of Chris\UserBundle\Entity\Role given, called in /Users/christianschade/bp/bp2/src/Chris/UserAdminBundle/Controller/AjaxGetController.php on line 305 and defined`   when i write in the controller         $user->removeRole( $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Role')->findRoleByName("ROLE_HAUSMEISTER"));

Comment: @MikadoJoe add `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;` and it'll work :)

Comment: sorry i really have no idea

Comment: In your user class, after the line `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;` add that line I mentioned.

Comment: how to use the removeRole() ? it wants an role interface as parameter. i just have role objects

Comment: Your Role objects are instances of RoleInerface as Role implements RoleInerface. It should be fine

Comment: hmm `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Chris\UserBundle\Entity\User::removeRole() must be an instance of Chris\UserBundle\Entity\RoleInterface, instance of Chris\UserBundle\Entity\Role given, called in /Users/christianschade/bp/bp2/src/Chris/UserAdminBundle/Controller/AjaxGetController.php on line 304 and defined`

Comment: thank you very much it works, just had yet to add use RoleInterface in User Class